# Exclude replies from official twitter search widget

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I have a twitter search-widget on my site with the following search: `from:account_name`.
But it now shows my twitterstream with all the replies to. I want to exclude those from the list.

Does anyone know how to do that? After searching there are a lot options with the REST-api but I just need it for the search-string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found an option to include retweets `include:retweets` so I tried to change that to `exclude:replies` and it worked!

My search-string is now: `from:account_name exclude:replies`